# MySQL Join query with Select Sorting by date & time in descending order

Tags: mysql, sorting, inner-join

Hi I want to filter the last invoice status using subscription id, but I can't, I am facing below issue
[image]

Query i am trying:-

```
    SELECT sub.ID,bs_invoice.BS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID,bs_invoice.CREATEDATE,bs_invoice.PAYMENT_STATUS 
FROM bs_subscription sub  
    INNER JOIN bs_invoice invo 
        on sub.ID=invo.BS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT BS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID, MAX(date) CREATEDATE
        FROM bs_invoice 
        GROUP BY BS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID 
    ) b ON invo.BS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=b.BS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID AND 
            invo.CREATEDATE=b.CREATEDATE
WHERE sub.ID=100;
```

Comment: there is no error, make a query tab and  copy the command, it will run

Comment: correct below commended like causing some error, I wasted more time because of this. thanks @nbk

Comment: Maybe instead of using `#` to comment, try wrapping them in `/**/` like `/* your commented codes here */`.